# How to make player/enemy change colour when hit?

Tags: python, pygame

When the player or enemy is hit, I want their sprite to change to red. essentially, I want a transparent red effect over the sprite. Does pygame offer a way to do this? (I'm using multiple images as the characters are animated, so creating a red sprite and just blitting that instead of the normal one won't work)

Comment: Pygame Surfaces can have alpha channel to add transparency. Do your images have a background which should not be reddened? If not, it's easy to do, if yes, it becomes more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame is low level, so you have to write your own function to do it. I  played a bit and found a nice way.
Here I assume that the images to be reddened have a transparency set with **pixel alphas** (i.e. each pixel has its own alpha value). This will let me to control where the reddening happens, and for example prevent a trasparent background from being reddened.
To be sure to use pixel alphas, when loading your images use `.convert_alpha()`.

The steps are the following:

1. Make a redshade. Create a Surface with pixel alphas, fill it with red color with a transparency value equal for each pixel. Choose an alpha value you think is best suited for your case (the more transparent is, the lighter will be the reddening effect).
2. Merge the alpha channel of the redshade with the alpha channel of the image to be reddened. Keep the lowest (most transparent) value for each pixel. You can do this quite efficiently with the [surfarray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module and *numpy*.
3. Blit the redshade surface on the surface of your Sprite. This will redden it.
4. Blit the reddened Sprite surface to the display.

This is the code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

def reddening(surf):
    """surf: pygame.Surface to be reddened. The function returns a new surface."""
    #making a red shade with transparency
    redshade = pygame.Surface(surf.get_rect().size).convert_alpha()
    redshade.fill((255, 0, 0, 100)) #red with alpha

    #merging the alpha chanel of base image on the redshade, keeping minimum values (most transparent) in each pixel
    alpha_basemask = pygame.surfarray.array_alpha(surf)
    alpha_redmask = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(redshade)
    np.minimum(alpha_basemask, alpha_redmask, out=alpha_redmask)

    #deleting the alpha_redmask reference to unlock redshade (or it cannot be blit)
    del alpha_redmask

    #reddening a copy of the original image
    redsurf = surf.copy()
    redsurf.blit(redshade, (0, 0))

    return redsurf

#loading a base image with transparency
surf_base = pygame.image.load('testcolim_walpha.png').convert_alpha()
red_surf = reddening(surf_base)

screen.blit(red_surf, (100, 200))

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

To show the effect, this is the original `'testimage.png'` (it's rectangular with a surrounding alpha channel to make the ellipse):

[image: original image]

And this is the reddened image with the code above:

[image: reddened image]

#### How to use it in an animation

Here there is no animation, it's static. But the idea is the same. Use the reddening function to redden each Sprite image during each frame of the animation.
To make your game faster, you can redden all the images once, store them, and switch from the original non-reddened to the reddened ones according to your game logic (hit point value or whatever).